# Converting javascript array data into an object

Tags: javascript

convert this type of data

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'hcs_utils', starCount: 0 },
  { name: 'K', starCount: 0 },
  { name: 'Heroes of Wesnoth', starCount: 0 },
  { name: 'Leiningen', starCount: 1 },
  { name: 'TearDownWalls', starCount: 1 }]
```

into this kind of object {"K":5, "Leiningen":4, ...}

Comment: And your code to try this was?

Comment: question solved ! thank you

Comment: That being the case, please *do* visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and/or take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  { name: "hcs_utils", starCount: 0 },
  { name: "K", starCount: 0 },
  { name: "Heroes of Wesnoth", starCount: 0 },
  { name: "Leiningen", starCount: 1 },
  { name: "TearDownWalls", starCount: 1 },
];

/* 
    // desired format
    {
        "hcs_utils": 0,
        "K": 0,
        // so on 
    }

*/

const formattedDataArray = data.map((each) => {
  const { name, starCount } = each;
  return {
    [name.toString()]: starCount,
  };
});

console.log("formattedDataArray is", formattedDataArray);

// with reduce

const resultWithReduce = formattedDataArray.reduce((prev, current) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    ...current,
  };
}, {});

console.log("resultWithReduce is", resultWithReduce);

// without reduce

let resutlWithoutReduce = {};

formattedDataArray.forEach((eachElement) => {
  const key = Object.keys(eachElement)[0];
  const value = Object.values(eachElement)[0];
  resutlWithoutReduce[key] = value;
});

console.log("resultWithoutReduce is", resutlWithoutReduce);
```

Hope it helps!